# Error when using class of models instead of using Tuple

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model

I have parent class of my models:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public ThemesModel themesModel { get; set; }
    public ThemeGroupsModel themesGroupsModel { get; set; }
    public ThemeTypsModel themesTypesModel { get; set; }
}
```

I use it in my method:

```
public List<MyModel> getAllTheme()
{
    List<MyModel> myModelList = new List<MyModel>();
    MyModel myModelTemp;
    using (var context = new EShopThemeDBEntities(idbconnection.ConnStr))
    {
        var ThemeTypeQ = (//some queries... ).ToList();

        if (ThemeTypeQ != null)
        {
             foreach (var item in ThemeTypeQ)
             {
                   myModelTemp = new MyModel();
                   myModelTemp.themesTypesModel.ThemeTypeName = item.ThemeTypeName;
                      .
                      .
                      .
             } 
        } 
    }

    return myModelList;   
 }
```

I get error on this line:

> myModelTemp.themesTypesModel.ThemeTypeName = item.ThemeTypeName;

error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I had used `Tuple<ThemeTypsModel, ThemesModel, ThemeGroupsModel>` instead of using `MyModel` and my project had worked before.

What should I do to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I solve it myself by changing MyModel.cs to this:

```
public class MyModel
{
public ThemesModel themesModel { get; set; }
public ThemeGroupsModel themesGroupsModel { get; set; }
public ThemeTypsModel themesTypesModel { get; set; }

  public MyModel()
    {
        themesModel = new ThemesModel();
        themesGroupsModel = new ThemeGroupsModel();
        themesTypesModel = new ThemeTypsModel();
    }
```

}

i don't delete my question to use by others who have the same problem.